# Как вывести данные из postgresql в телеграм бот на aiogram

Tags: python, postgresql, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
async def sql_read1(message): 
    for ret in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM venu').fetchall(): 
        await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена {ret[-1]}')

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=FSMAdmin.photo)
async def load_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext): 
    if message.from_user.id == ID: 
        async with state.proxy() as data: 
            data['photo'] = message.photo[0].file_id 
            await FSMAdmin.next() 
            await message.reply("Тепер введи назву")
```

В базе данных 4 колонки img, name, description, price  (img  -  картинка переведенная в текст)
Теперь не получается вывести данные из нее в бот.
То бишь при нажатии на кнопку должно последовательно идти "картинка" "имя" "описание" "цена" и т.д. по всем строкам в таблице бд.

Comment: Приложите код в виде текста.

Comment: async def sql_read1(message):
 for ret in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM venu').fetchall():
  await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена {ret[-1]}')

Comment: @dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=FSMAdmin.photo)
async def load_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
 if message.from_user.id == ID:
  async with state.proxy() as data:
   data['photo'] = message.photo[0].file_id
  await FSMAdmin.next()
  await message.reply("Тепер введи назву")